# Analyze trend given a set of points

Tags: time-series, econometrics, pattern-recognition, trend

Suppose I have a set of N values representing EUR/USD rate... [ 1.10 , 1.20 , 1.25, 1.20, 1.19 ]

Which is the simplest way for analyzing if values tend to raise or tend to fall?

I'm looking for a simple and computationally efficient algorithm to use and write into a low level programming language like C.

Thanks

Comment: The simplest way I have ever encountered (at least among the ways that make quantitative use of the data) is to compare the last value to the first. For some purposes and some data it works just fine. For most purposes it's inferior. But that raises the question, inferior in what sense? And to answer that requires knowing why you're "analyzing" these data and what conclusions you intend to draw from the analysis, as well as having some understanding of the data and how they vary. If you could edit this post to provide this information you would likely get better answers.

Comment: Any trades or business decisions based on an analysis of trends in such data will have consequences. The financial components of those consequences will surely dwarf any savings that could be obtained by writing simple low-level code compared to performing a good statistical analysis of the data and writing *appropriate* code, even if it ends up being complex.

Comment: It is just a school project...

Comment: Why not a simple least squares regression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time series data can be complicated.  In addition to any overall trend they can exhibit cyclic behavior over multiple, overlapping seasons; they can suddenly change; they can be driven by other complicated time series; variations around these gross behaviors can have complex random patterns that are correlated over time; and such variation can sometimes include unusually high or low values ("outliers").

For a simple project or in any application where a single estimate of an "overall trend" is desired, it must be made without further analysis of the data, it is understood to be crude, and must be rapidly and easily computed, a highly robust estimate of that trend can be obtained as follows:

1. Partition the data roughly into thirds according to time.
2. Identify the middle (median) dates and median values (USD in this case) in the first and last thirds.
3. Use these two points, (median date, median value), to characterize the trend.

One way to use that pair of points is to draw a line through it.  If you possibly can, display the data along with that line so the user can evaluate whether the line is an acceptable summary of the trend.

[image: Figure]

Notice that the two points used to draw the line--shown as black dots--are not necessarily part of the data.  Each one of them is just a typical value in its third of the time series.

The calculations are simple programming exercises and can be carried out in $O(n)$ time for $n$ data points.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to ask if there is any way to adapt current algorithm for something to be able to be runneable over time since O(n) won't work for a continuous increasingly amount of data. I have been doing something research and come up with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average . Am I well oriented? Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are asking a different question: nothing in your post mentions a "continuous increasing amount of data." That is so profoundly different than "having a set of $N$ values" that it suggests entirely different kinds of solutions.  This is why it is so important to post a question about the problem you actually have.  See our [help] for more guidance about asking questions. BTW, if you really want to you can update the medians in $O(\log(N))$ time (and $O(N)$ storage): use a heap to store the values.

Answer (score 1):

Answers will depend partly on what you mean by "tend to rise or fall".

Consider a situation which each period has a 99% chance of small growth (by 1%) and 1% chance of a large drop (a drop to 37% of the previous period's value) - e.g. one typical case: in 100 periods you'll increase 99 times and decrease once, but overall you'll end up down about 1%.

Does that count as "tend to rise", since you nearly always go up from one period to the next, or does it count as "tend to fall" since in the long run you will tend to end up lower than when you started?

The answer affects how you should measure it. If you think that's "tend to rise" you should look at something like the proportion of rises; if you think that's "tend to fall" you could look at something like the average percentage change (or average change in the logs)... which will tend to be somewhat similar to whuber's approach.